# What is the difference between an exact and a sufficient schedulability test?

Tags: algorithm, real-time, scheduling, job-scheduling

When it comes to scheduling some definitions should be completely understood. **Schedulabiltiy test** is one of them.

There is a book from Sanjoy K. Baruah (Multiprocessor Scheduling for Real-Time Systems) which explains **Schedulabilty test** as follows:

> Let **A** denote a scheduling algorithm. A sporadic task system **T** is said to be *A-schedulable*, if **A** meets all deadlines when scheduling each of the potentially infiinte different collection of jobs that could be generated by **T** [...]

There is also a distinction between **exact** and **sufficient** for **Schedulability tests**:

> A schedulabiltiy test is called *exact*, if it identifies **all A-schedulable** systems. The test is called *sufficient*, if it identifies **some A-schedulable** systems.

So, informally speaking, I can say, that a (in)equation which uses the parameters of the task system **T** (e.g. periods, deadlines) to  make a statement about the schedulabiltiy is a **Schedulability test**. So far I have understood.

But what does **exact** and **sufficient** mean in this context? For me, some algorithm is either *schedulable* or not (for all different collections of jobs). Can somebody give me an example or explain it in a simple way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You already have the definition.

An **exact** test will give you ALL schedulable systems.

A **sufficient** test can give you one and then stop.

Say you need to schedule 3 jobs. You need to run them one by one and there are no other constraints (any ordering works).

A **sufficient** test will tell you that you can schedule them in order 1,2,3.

A **exact** test will tell list all possible combinations of jobs.

Comment: Ok, i understand that. I just thought, the scheduling test just makes a statement about if that task set is schedulable by that algorithm or not. I was not aware that the test also delivers the schedule itself.